# Numpy genfromtxt skipping leading whitespace in each line

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, text, whitespace

```
import numpy as np

stuff ='       57107 1 1589 1 2201-1 1 1 1-1 111-1-1-1   3991555 1 2 1 1 695 0A65 -1 1 1 1 2-1-1 24546-1-1  -1 -1-1-1-1-1-1 2 1-155- 1 2 1 2 6 240 1 8 9 1 1-1 1 1 1 2 1 2 57 57 57 1 0 0 2 1 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 2-170-1-1 70-1-1-1-1 2-1 14080-1 80-1  697 2 5 5-1 2 3 5 2-1-1-1-1-1-1 -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 1-122 1 1 1 6-1-1-1 -1 1-1 1 2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 6 4840678-1-1 -1 -1 2-1-1-1 2 4-1-1 6-143-135-1 117-1 9-1 3 1 1 1-1-1-1-1-1-1  -1  -1  -1  0-1-1      0-1-1-1      -1      0-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1   3991555         0         0   3642944   3958306-1    -1-1 0 0 0 1 0-1 050 0 0 0 011 0 0 0-1-1-1-1 0 0-1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 0 0 0-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1\n       57107 1 1589 1 2201-1 1 1 1-1 111-1-1-1   3991555 1 2 1 1 695 0A65 -1 1 1 1 2-1-1 24546-1-1  -1 -1-1-1-1-1-1 2 3-154- 1 1 2 2 6 239 1 8 9 1 2-1 1 2 1 2 1 2 57 57 57 1 0 0 1 1 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 1 22420-1 44-1-1-1-1 2-1 2-12420 44-1   -1 1 5 5-1 1 3 5 2-1-1-1-1-1-1 -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 1-119 1 1 1 2-1-1-1 -1 1-1 1 2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 4 2630265-1-1 -1 -1 2-1-1-1 2 4-1 1 6-134-119-1 110-1 4-1 1 1 1 2-1-1-1-1-1-1  -1  -1  -1  0-1-1      0-1-1-1      -1      0-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1   3991555         0         0   3991555   3998325-1    -1-1 0 0 0 1 0-1 050 0 0 0 011 0 0 0-1-1-1-1 0 0-1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 0 0 0-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1\n       57108 1  912 1 1201-1 2 1 1-1 1 2-1-1-1   4478084 1 1 6 1 695 0A65 -1 1 2-1-1-1-1 24546-1-1  -1 -1-1-1-1-1-1 2 2-122- 6-1 1 2 6 240 1 8 9 0 1-1 0 0 2 2 7 2 57 57 57 1 0 0 1 1 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 2-140-1-1 40-1-1-111 125 2-115-1 15-1  321 2 5 5-1 2 3 3 2-1-1-1-1-1-1 -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 1-114 1 1 1 4-1 011 -1 1-1 1 4-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 2 4850889-1-1 -1 -1 2-1-1-1 2 2-1 2 8-144-142-1 118-112-1 3-1 1 1-1-1-1-1-1-1  -1  -1  -1  0-1-1      0-1-1-1      -1      0-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 1 2 2 2   4478084         0         0   4478084   4609610-1    -1-1 0 0 0 1 0-1 050 0 0 0 011 0 0 0-1-1-1-1 0 0-1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 0 0 0-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1 0 0 0'
filename = 'test.dat'
writer = open(filename, mode='w')
writer.write(stuff)
writer.close()

data = np.genfromtxt(filename,delimiter = ',', dtype=None, encoding='utf-8')
```

Running the above code returns 3 rows with each line of text, however it skips the whitespace in the beginning of each line. How do I include it?

The variables have different positions and lengths (ex. variable A is at position 32 with length 2 and variable B is at position 68 with length 1), so it matters that the whitespace is included so that I can parse the string correctly.

I am also stuck with using numpy genfromtxt because the files I work with sometimes have null characters (I've tried using pd.read_csv(filename, dtype=None, encoding='utf-8')). When using read_csv, pandas treats the null characters as end of line terminators, so I lose all the text after the null chars.

Comment: NumPy's `genfromtext` function returns a `numpy.ndarray` object, which contains numbers. Why would you want whitespace in a `numpy.ndarray` object? Also, null characters represent the end of a line, so why would you have anything after your null characters in your text? Which specific null characters are you using, and where?

Comment: The files I'm working with are just like that - I don't have control over it. The positions/lengths given for each variable account for the whitespace so I need the whole line as a string so I can parse it by those positions/lengths.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy loadtxt instead of genfromtxt fixed the issue.

EDIT: Upon advice from @hpaulj, using filename.readlines() would be better suitable for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you are content with reading each line as string ('U814' dtype), why not just use `file.readlines()`?  You'll get a list of lines, each line being same as you get from `loadtxt` (except for `\n`).  `genfromtxt/loadtxt` are meant for files where you want to split the columns into columns or fields of an array.  In your case that would mean using default whitespace delimiter.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I totally forgot about readlines. I like that better. It also handles the null characters.